# flex (python PLY) regex for strings

Tags: ply

I'm using the python module PLY to write a parser, and I am implementing as I go. I have a simple rule to detect strings:

```
r'("|\').*("|\')'
```

When lexer errors are thrown I have this:

```
def t_error (t) :
    print 'Illegal lexer input line ' + str(t.lineno) + ' ' + t.value[:16]
    sys.exit(-1)
```

When I feed my parser the following input:

```
parse("preg_match('%^[\*\%]+$%', $keywords)")
```

I get back this in return:

```
Illegal lexer input line 1 %^[\*\%]+$%', $k
```

My questions are:

1) Why am I not parsing this string? It seems like my regex should properly handle this string.

2) How can I fix this?

edit:

I have narrowed the problem down a bit. The following strings throw illegal lexer input errors by themselves:

```
'%'
'^'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this regex were working it isn't *quite* doing what you want it to, for example it would accept `"this'`, which isn't really a string. This is also the cause of the "illegal lexer input"...

After having done it's job and found the first string in `"preg_match('` the lexer is then upset when each of the next 11 characters `%^[\*\%]+$%` are illegal (and not in `t_ignore`), since they don't even start with `"` or `'`.

.

Try doing this with two cases for `"` and `'`: *"Starts with quote, some things which aren't quote, ends with quote."* That is:

```
r'("[^"]*")|(\'[^\']*\')'
```

Or, if you want to include escaped speech marks:

```
r'("(\\"|[^"])*")|(\'(\\\'|[^\'])*\')'
```

Comment: just a note: ".*" looks for the longest string, so ("foo", "bar") would be treated as '(', '"foo", "bar"', ')'.  Use ".*?" which means "shortest string", so it would return '(', '"foo"', '"bar"', ')' instead.